# Receiving multiple variables from a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found out how to send multiple variables on SO using this:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1:3000?var1=" + name + "&var2=test", true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

    }
}
```

The problem is, my node.js `var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,false).query;` turns into `queryObject = 'var1=Robert&var2=test'`. I was expecting `var1='Robert'; var2='test';` Is there a way to do that with a command?

The only way I can think of doing it is by doing this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1:3000? + name + "&test", true);

and then node.js 

var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,false).query;
var kk = queryObject.split("&");
```

but this way doesn't seem to work either for some reason. Is there a simple command that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the first way you had it:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1:3000?var1=test1&var2=test2", true);
```

and use [queryString.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options) to pull out the variables you want to be able to read.

```
var res = querystring.parse(req.url)
```

res will be

```
{ 
  var1: 'test1',
  var2: 'test2'
}
```

Comment: Doh of course I miss something so easy, exactly what I needed thank you very much. After reading up on their API if I use true instead of false it automatically queryString's it, for example: `var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;` Thanks again sorry for the boring qeustion